# How can you copy text from source pdf that includes the formatting information?

Tags: pdf, itext

I am using iText7 to experiment copying a load of seperate pdfs into 1 single pdf document. It's easy to copy the text like this:

```
var sourcePage = sourcePdf.GetPage(i + 1);
var strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(sourcePage, strategy);                        

var currentText = Encoding.
    UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text)));

PdfFont regular = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA);
PdfFont bold = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA_BOLD);
Text first = new Text(currentText).SetFont(regular);
Text second = new Text("TEST TEST").SetFont(bold);
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph().Add(first).Add(second);

outDocument.Add(paragraph);
```

Here I am testing Helvetica font but its needs to be the same as the source.

The variables "text" and "currentText" are just plain text. How do I get the metadata? The destination document needs to have the same formatting.

Comment: You can copy the whole source page into your new one. And by setting the clip path accordingly, you can cut away everything but the required area. Or by first redacting away everything else (which would be more secure). Alternatively you can create a text extraction strategy that tries to extract all data relevant here. That being said, what do you intend to achieve using `var currentText = Encoding.
    UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(text)));`?

Comment: The UTF8 encoding was just a test and could have been removed from the example. How do I set the clip path? Sounds like a custom text strategy, not sure how to do that.

Comment: Something else that could really help. How do I get the ending position of the content on a pdf? the position should be a float and defines where to position the next pdf I want to copy to the source. This way I can copy 2 docs onto the same page.

Comment: I could use CopyAsFormXObject instead of reading the text, but then I need to know where to position the next page.

Comment: I am tackling this a different way now. I have got the Y coordinates I need, but I get some odd results..Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57316944/trying-to-copy-source-pdf-to-destination-at-specific-y-position

Comment: For multiple source pages onto a single target page, the use of `CopyAsFormXObject` is indeed appropriate. *"How do I get the ending position of the content on a pdf?"* - Did you put the existing content onto the page? Then you should know, after all you added the content. Otherwise, you can analyze what's on the page using a `PDFStreamEngine`

Comment: I have the ending position I want now, I used a custom event listener to get the location of a CharacterRenderInfo. The issue is when I use those Y values to position something it doesnt appear where I expect. The Y values look accurate according to the results.. ie 400 is in the middle etc. The problem is now with CopyAsFormXObject . Please the link above.